# How to get the exit code from a file ran using javascript child_process.execFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, return-value, child-process, exit-code

**Here is my python code:**

```
#!/bin/python
import sys
sys.exit(4)
```

**Here is my javascript**

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile
exec('./script.py', (err, data) => { if(err) { console.log(err.status) } })
```

But it doesn't work because there is not such thing as err.status
what I want to have in my console logs is '4'.

Comment: If you intend to share the script use `#!/usr/bin/env python` instead, this ensures your OS will lookup the configured path to the python interpreter via `PATH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't `err.status`, but there is `err.code`.

This should work:

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile
exec('./script.py', (err, data) => { if(err) { console.log(err.code) } })
```

There is also `err.signal` and `err.killed`

From the nodejs docs:

> On success, error will be null. On error, error will be an instance of
>   Error. The error.code property will be the exit code of the child
>   process while error.signal will be set to the signal that terminated
>   the process. Any exit code other than 0 is considered to be an error.

(https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback)

Answer (score 1):

`execFile`'s callback get 3 arguments:

- `error`, if there was.
- `stdout`, the stdout of process.
- `stderr`, the stderr of the process.

So, by checking the `stderr`, you should be able to achieve the expected result:

```js
var exec = require('child_process').execFile
exec('./script.py',(err,stdout,stderr)=>{console.log(stderr)})
```

See this in the [Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback)